# Problems with wget AWS ubuntu apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, wget

I am trying to use wget to download from my AWS ubuntu server with apache2. I have tried several different options but they all result in either a file by the directory name, or an index.html file.

There are 3 pictures and an ogg format video in the directory.

This is the wget I am using:

`wget -N -np http://domainorIP/dir/dir2/dirtodownload/`

- -N is only download files that are newer
- -np do not ascend to parent directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `wget` only downloads the URL you give it, not any resources linked from an HTML page.  To follow these links, you need the `-r` (or `--recursive`) option.

There is also the `--page-requisites` option which downloads any resources necessary for displaying the page you give it, such as inline images and stylesheets.

There are also "grouped" options such as `--mirror` which include `-r` along with several other options that are useful for mirroring.

The man page is enormous because `wget` has a lot of features.  The section on `Recursive Retrieval Options` would be well worth your time to read.

Answer (score 0):

Download a CLI browser and download the desired files, you can use ELinks or W3M

```
apt-get install elinks w3m
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had success in getting either `curl` or `wget` to download files which are being served from an Apache server where `indexing directories` is enabled. I'm thinking this is your problem as well. The directories show up like this when you browse them:

[image: image of Apache indexed directory]

In Apache they're enabled like this for example:

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/pdfs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Using the shell you're options are limited to getting the list of files and then downloading them one at a time using a command like this one:

```
% URL="http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/"
% curl -s $URL | \
     grep "href" | \
     grep -v "C=D;O=A" | \
     sed "s#^.*href=\"#$URL#" | \
     sed 's/">.*$//' | \
     xargs wget
```

Breaking this down:

```
 - URL="..."                - is the URL I want to download files from
 - curl -s $URL             - get's the contents of the index.html generated by Apache
 - grep "href"              - get lines that contain only href
 - grep -v "C=D;O=A"        - eliminate the header bar line generated by Apache
 - sed "s#^.*href=\"#$URL#" - replace .*href=" lines with URL
 - sed 's/">.*$//'          - remove trailing characters >.*$
 - xargs wget               - download each file using wget
```

You can run this as a single command:

```
url="http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/"; curl -s $url | grep "href" | grep -v "C=D;O=A" | sed "s#^.*href=\"#$url#" | sed 's/">.*$//' | xargs wget
```

Running it results in the following files getting downloaded:

```
% ls -l
total 1652
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 1351400 Oct  8 23:35 Anatomy-of-the-Linux-file-system.mht
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml     485 Oct 11 00:42 eratosthenes_prime_sieve.pl_.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   27191 Oct  3 21:42 Selection_005-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   24202 Oct  3 21:42 Selection_005.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   27141 Oct  3 21:42 Selection_006-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   24906 Oct  3 21:42 Selection_006.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   25783 Oct  3 22:17 Selection_007-150x150.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  111915 Oct  3 22:17 Selection_007-650x180.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   48109 Oct  4 09:57 Selection_007-e1349359020755.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   29336 Oct  3 22:17 Selection_007.png
```

Comment: Although I have the index file turned on at this point it has created some problems and must now be turned off.